# FabricのMavenリポジトリが401を返すためGradleのビルドが遅い

Tags: android, gradle, maven, twitter-fabric

[Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/)のMavenリポジトリから新しい[Fabric](https://dev.twitter.com/products/fabric)のリポジトリにした後、Gradleのビルドが信じられないほど遅くなりました。

この問題はGradleが依存関係を解決するうえで、FabricのMavenリポジトリが 401 Unauthorized を返しているので引き起こされているように見えます。

```
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: https://maven.fabric.io/repo/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/maven-metadata.xml]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: https://maven.fabric.io/repo/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: https://maven.fabric.io/repo/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: https://maven.fabric.io/repo/com/google/android/gms/play-services/maven-metadata.xml]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: https://maven.fabric.io/repo/com/android/support/support-annotations/21.0.2/support-annotations-21.0.2.pom]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: https://maven.fabric.io/repo/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/19.0.1/mediarouter-v7-19.0.1.pom]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: https://maven.fabric.io/repo/com/android/support/support-annotations/maven-metadata.xml]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: https://maven.fabric.io/repo/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/maven-metadata.xml]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: https://maven.fabric.io/repo/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: https://maven.fabric.io/repo/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: https://maven.fabric.io/repo/com/google/android/gms/play-services/maven-metadata.xml]
```

古いCrashlyticsのMavenリポジトリは 401 Unauthorized を返してきません。

何か解決策はあるでしょうか。

---

これは、実際に私が遭遇した問題を解決できたStack Overflowの質問を翻訳し、編集したものです。  
[android - Fabric maven repo causes slow gradle builds - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117609/fabric-maven-repo-causes-slow-gradle-builds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`build.gradle`

```
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }
```

を

```
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
```

に置換します。

以前はFabricに載っているやり方に正しくないURLが記載されていたため、この問題が発生します。
https://fabric.io/downloads/gradle

現時点でも、Twitterの方のドキュメントは修正されていません。
[Integrate the SDK | Twitter Developers](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/integrate)

---

この変更のみで、以前は1分以上かかっていたところが、15秒を切るようになりました。

```
./gradlew clean assembleProductionDebug
Total time: 2 mins 35.675 secs
./gradlew assembleProductionDebug
Total time: 1 mins 13.216 secs
```

ここで、FabricのリポジトリURLを正しいものにすると

```
./gradlew clean assembleProductionDebug
Total time: 1 mins 36.05 secs
./gradlew assembleProductionDebug
Total time: 13.338 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

本質的な対策ではありませんが、ネットワークに係る問題については
追加時以外はPreferences-GradleでOffline workにチェックを入れておくことでも解決できます。